# object HTMLInputElement without form in jquery html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables, object

I have a function

```
function changeval(fid) { 
    $('#'+fid).html('<span onclick="alert(' + fid + ');" class="link">Change</span>');
}
```

On first place fid appears as normal variable and affects the div I need (with id that is 'fid'), but on alert function it appears as [object HTMLInputElement]. I just don`t know what to do... I think I have tried everything...

Comment: You'll need to show us how `changeval()` is being called.

Comment: Simply onclick="changeval('divone');"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap the 'fid' with quotes in the html output, without quotes javascript alert the first element with `'id="fid's content"'`.

[View here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oBafF)

```
function changeval(fid) { 
  $('#'+fid).html('<span onclick="alert(\'' + fid + '\');" class="link">Change</span>');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would remove the "onclick" and do it like this(using jquery 1.7.1)....

```
$(function() {//Document ready

    $('body').on('click','.link',function(){
        //Do what you want i.e...
        alert($(this).parent().attr('id'));
        alert($(this).parent().html());
    });

});

function changeval(fid) { 
    $('#'+fid).html('<span class="link">Change</span>');
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Not really because I need this onclick for a lot of different actions. I could also use switch but it wouldn`t be the best option.

Comment: What do you actually want to retrieve? Do you want to alert back the elements "fid" i.e you have an element with id "divone". When you click on the span you want to show "divone"?